# XSLT Change Inner String

Tags: html, xslt

I am using XSLT inside HTML to manipulate some XML that is provided to me. To give some background on what I need to do:

I will receive some XML in the format

```
<base>
    <string>
        "Hi, this is a String"
    </string>
    <redlist>
        <red>
            <start>3</start>
            <end>5</end>
        </red>
        <red>
            <start>9</start>
            <end>11</end>
        </red>
    </redlist>
</base>
```

This should then ultimately produce some output HTML that will highlight the inclusive characters denoted in the `<red>` tag in red. So this should output "Hi, this is a String", with the "th" and "is" part in red.

I reckon I need to do some sort of fancy processing with substrings, but don't really know how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Update:

I have the following -

```
<xsl:for-each select="base/redlist">
    <span style="color:black">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(../string, 0, red/start)">
    </span>
    <span style="color:red">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(../string, red/start, red/end)">
    </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But obviously this doesn't work due to the 0 in each iteration of the for-each loop.

Comment: Surely 3-5 would ensure only `th` is turned red, not `this `.

Comment: Thanks, I changed numbers halfway through and forgot to update. Have updated the main question now

Comment: What about the `substring` function?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the last optional argument to `substring()` is the length of the substring, not the end index.

Something like the following could be one approach. You need to adjust it accordingly depending on whether your indices are zero- or one-based and whether you intend the quotes to be part of the string or not.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="base">
    <span style="color:black">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="redlist/red">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space(string)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="red">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::red)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, start - 1)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <span style="color:red">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, start, end - start)"/>
    </span>
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::red"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$next">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, end, $next/start - end)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, end)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was going to propose a use of call-template in a similar fashion to this, but I really like your solution here with respect to the fact that the template is applied to with red list with a parameter rather than the other way around.